# Determine whether callback is using all parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how I can determine whether a user of my plugin is using any or all of the parameters of my callback.  For example I want the user to have optional error handling when using my callback.  Here is the code:

```
function myFunc(userInput, callback) {
  switch (userInput)
  case 'someInput':
  var = data;
  if (someError) {var err = someError;}
  callback(err, data);
  break;
}
```

Now if the user chooses they can look for an error in the callback like so:

```
myFunc('someInput', function(err, data) {
console.log(err);
console.log(data);
});
```

But if the user chooses to ignore any errors I still want the data to be sent like so:

```
myFunc('someInput', function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

However, if there is an error and since I've declared any errors as the first parameter, the above example will log any error messages in the `data` and not the data itself.  How can I know when the user doesn't include the `err` in their callback?

Comment: Reverse the parameters?  The optional parameter should be last and the required first.  If both are optional then instead have one parameter which is an object containing properties.

Comment: You can use arguments https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments to determine the number and type of all arguments passed.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It's pretty common in node.js to provice `error` as the first argument to a callback -regardless of whether or not there's an error. Not that this question is about node.js, but it's a pattern which conflicts with your suggestion.

Comment: @canon I got this idea originally from node.js.  Do you know how it is implemented there?  If so, would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @canon I just wanted to clarify that my comment does not actually conflict at all with what you describe of node.js.  When I said "optional" I meant a parameter that may or may not be passed **at all**.  If the parameter is always passed but may be null, that is not optional in the sense I was describing.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I was simply saying that the error argument isn't _optional_ in that context. Swapping the order doesn't make much sense if you're purposefully employing an error-first pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js, which you seem to be emulating, uses an error-first callback pattern. In the event that there's no error, it simply passes `null` for the first argument. There's no interrogation of the callback which would affect how the callback is invoked.

Any attempt to sniff arguments is pretty sketchy. The callback *could* be using your arguments without actually specifying them in the function signature:

```
function() {
   var args = arguments;
   var err = args[0];
   var data = args[1];
   // do stuff
}
```

Or they may not even care what your arguments are at all.

```
function() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

On the optional arguments front, you could simply pass a single object containing both values:

```
callback({
    error: err, 
    data: data
});
```

At the end of the day, it's the consumer of the plugin who has to conform to your pattern. Just be consistent about it... and don't worry about what they do with those values; that's their business.

Comment: You bring up some use cases that I didn't think of.  Thank you for that.  As I asked you in my original question's comments: Do you know how node.js handles the error as the first parameter?

Comment: @user3669257 it passes either an error object or `null` as the first argument.

Comment: I see thank you!  I'm marking your answer as correct because I feel that you've explained why my approach shouldn't be used in the first place due to the fact that I have no control over how the consumer used my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in js have property `length`, that show number of arguments of a function.

`(function(x,y){}).length >> 2`

`(function(){}).length >> 0`

**Edit:** please, be careful with this approach. User can define callback as a function with no arguments like `function(){...}` and then use `arguments` list inside to see all values passed.

Answer (score 1):

While you can check the arity of a function using its [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length),  that will only tell you how many params the function expects, not what they are or what it will do with them.

A more traditional solution is to put optional parameters last in the list, and fill from the beginning. In this case, `data` should come before `err`, as it will always be provided and `err` may not be. I would prefer this solution in most cases.

Another option is to use named parameters, implemented in JS by passing a single parameter that is a hash, and allow the function to fetch what it wants from there. Then you would simply pass `params`, being something like `{data: x, err: y}`.

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for.  I got this whole idea from node.js which adds its error handling to the first parameter of a callback.  In client side scripting I would probably use this method.